# Was bedeutet „Feuchtwangen“ auf Englisch?

Tags: meaning, etymology, person-names, place-name

A professional acquaintance has the last name Feuchtwanger, which prompted learning of the German city [Feuchtwangen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feuchtwangen) — from which an ancestor presumably *kam aus*. The literal meaning seems to be “wet cheeks.” Is this accurate? Does the name’s origin help understand the colorful name? Is it used idiomatically?

Answer (score 11):

The problem with names is that long age often obscures their origin: The original meaning is lost or reinterpreted; changes in pronunciation and spelling occur.

The German Wikipedia entry for [Feuchtwangen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feuchtwangen#Ortsname) references *Deutsches Ortsnamenbuch* (2012), edited by Manfred Niemeyer, with the claim that *Feuchtwangen* is a combination of a misinterpretation of *Fichte* (compare MHG *viehte* "Fichte/spruce", *viuhte* "feucht/wet") and *Wang*. The masculine noun *Wang* "Feld/field" no longer exists (but is probably related to the feminine noun *Wange*, "cheek").

For *Wang* and names based on it, see [DWB: Wang](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemid=W06416), specifically under 4).

However, Wilhelm Schaudig (1927), *[Geschichte der Stadt und des ehemaligen Stifts Feuchtwangen](http://www.geschichte-feuchtwangen.de/Schaudig/SchdS001.htm)* maintains that *Feucht-* does not signify "Fichte" and *Feuchtwangen* is in fact simply "wet field".

> Die Bedeutung des Namens ist: Die Ansiedlung bei der "feuchten Aue", vom althochdeutschen fiucht, feucht, und wanc, die Aue, das Feld.

Accompanied by the following footnote addressing the interpretation of the first part of the name as *Fichte*:

> Man will zwar den Namen auch von "Fichte" (althochdeutsch fiuhta, mittelhochdeutsch viehte) ableiten. Förstemann sagt, Feuchtwangen gehörte zu "Fichte", das Wort feucht humidus sei in Ortsnamen sehr zweifelhaft. Dr. Wasserzieher führt in seinem Buch "Woher?" den Namen ebenfalls auf Fichte zurück. Aber es sind gewichtige Gründe, die uns an "feucht" festhalten lassen. Wenn wanc soviel als "Aue", und unter diesem "Wiesenland" zu verstehen ist (Wasserzieher), so ist doch das Bestimmungswort "Fichte" hiebei nicht denkbar. Vor allem aber legt der Name des alten, in der Nähe auf Sand gelegenen Ortes Dürrwangen (ahd. durri) und der des ebenfalls nahen "zum dürren Hof", jetzt Thürnhofen, für das auf wasserhaltendem Tonboden gegründete Feuchtwangen das "feucht" unbedingt nahe.

Schaudig's argument is twofold: To his mind, *feucht* goes better with "(open) field" than "Fichte"; and there is a nearby place called *Dürrwangen*, "dry field".

Answer (score 9):

The [German Wikipedia entry to Feuchtwangen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feuchtwangen#Ortsname) offers the etymology.

> Der Name geht auf das Bestimmungswort fiuchta (Fichte) und das Grundwort -wang (Wiesenhang, Aue) zurück. Es liegt *Fiuhtinwanga (mit Fichten bestandener Wiesenhang) als Ausgangswort vor. Später wurde fälschlicherweise zu fuht (feucht) dissimiliert.

> Tye name originates from *fiuchta* (Fichte, engl. spruce) and *-wang* (Wiesehang engl. meadow hillside). The starting word was *Fiuhtingwanga* (hillside overgrown with spruces). Later on this erroneously was dissimilated to *fuht* (feucht, engl. wet, moist).

The word is neither used idiomatically nor anywhere else besides the city name, to my knowledge.